# How to listen for keyspace notifications of redis cluster in java using jedis client?

Tags: java, redis, jedis, redis-cluster

I am setting a server which can listen and send message about any event occur in the redis database. I am successful in getting notified about new events for redis host and port but not able to do so for redis cluster.

```java
GenericObjectPoolConfig config = new GenericObjectPoolConfig();
config.setMaxTotal(30);
config.setMaxWaitMillis(2000);

Set<HostAndPort> jedisClusterNode = new HashSet<HostAndPort>();
jedisClusterNode.add(new HostAndPort("127.0.0.1", 7001));

JedisCluster cluster1 = new JedisCluster(jedisClusterNode, config);

String redisProperties = cluster1.getClusterNodes().toString().replaceAll("[{}]", "");
Set<HostAndPort> nodes = new HashSet<>();
String[] mainArray = redisProperties.split(",");
for (int i = 0; i < mainArray.length; i++) {
    String[] equalArray = mainArray[i].split("=");
    String mainData = equalArray[0];
    String[] ipPortPair = mainData.split(":");
    nodes.add(new HostAndPort(ipPortPair[0].trim(), Integer.valueOf(ipPortPair[1].trim())));
}

JedisCluster cluster = new JedisCluster(nodes, 10000, 1000, 1, config);
jedis.configSet("notify-keyspace-events", "AKE"); // For all kind of events
jedis.psubscribe(new KeyListenerCluster(), "__keyevent@0__:*");
```

I am able to perform every other operation in using the redis-cluster but not able to do one thing.

```java
cluster.configSet("notify-keyspace-events", "AKE"); // For all kind of events
cluster.psubscribe(new KeyListenerCluster(), "__keyevent@0__:*");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am facing the same issue, Keyspace notification is working intermittently (works 6 or 7 times out of 10). I read that one needs to subscribe to all of the master nodes in order to get the notifications. If it helps I have pasted my config file below :

```
KeySpaceNotificationMessageListener keySpaceNotificationMessageListener;

    @Value("${spring.redis.cluster.nodes}")
    private String hostsAndPorts;

    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory(RedisClusterConfiguration redisClusterConfiguration)
    {
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisClusterConfiguration);
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter messageListener() {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(keySpaceNotificationMessageListener);
    }


    @Bean(name = "cacheManager1")
    @Primary
    public RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager1()
    {
        RedisCacheConfiguration redisCacheConfiguration = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                .disableCachingNullValues()
                .entryTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
                .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(RedisSerializer.json()));

        redisCacheConfiguration.usePrefix();

        return RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManagerBuilder.fromConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory(redisClusterConfiguration()))
                .cacheDefaults(redisCacheConfiguration).build();

    }

    @Bean(name = "cacheManager2")
    public RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager2( JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory)
    {
        RedisCacheConfiguration redisCacheConfiguration = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                .disableCachingNullValues()
                .entryTtl(Duration.ofDays(1))
                .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(RedisSerializer.json()));

        redisCacheConfiguration.usePrefix();

        return RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManagerBuilder.fromConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory(redisClusterConfiguration()))
                .cacheDefaults(redisCacheConfiguration).build();

    }

    @Bean
    public RedisClusterConfiguration redisClusterConfiguration()
    {
        String [] redisHostAndPorts = hostsAndPorts.split(",");

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(redisHostAndPorts));
        RedisClusterConfiguration redisClusterConfiguration = new RedisClusterConfiguration(Arrays.asList(redisHostAndPorts));
        return redisClusterConfiguration;
    }

    @Bean
    RedisMessageListenerContainer redisContainer() {
        final RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory(redisClusterConfiguration()));
        container.addMessageListener(messageListener(), new PatternTopic("__keyspace@*:*"));
        container.setTaskExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4));
        return container;
    }

    public void setKeySpaceNotificationMessageListener(KeySpaceNotificationMessageListener keySpaceNotificationMessageListener)
    {
        this.keySpaceNotificationMessageListener = keySpaceNotificationMessageListener;
    }
```